# Binding On Click Function Angular 2

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, angular

I am porting in some components from another app which was build with angular-cli to a mean stack app. There are some collapsable cards in the original app and when I move them over with their respective functions to watch for when they are expanded or collapsed I get this error,

> Can't bind to 'collapse' since it isn't a known property of 'div'.
>   ("btn-block responsive-width" (click)="isCollapsed = !isCollapsed">§
>   601 Short title          ][collapse]="isCollapsed"
>   class="card card-block card-header">

In the component.html file this is the onClick function

```
<button type="button" class="building btn btn-info btn-primary btn-default btn-lg btn-block responsive-width" (click)="isCollapsed1 = !isCollapsed1">§ 602 Congressional findings and statement of purpose</button>
            <div [collapse]="isCollapsed1" class="card card-block card-header">
```

and in the component.ts file I have a boolean to check for its state,

```
export class FcraComponent {

  constructor() { }
  public isCollapsed:boolean = true;
```

I used ng2-bootstrap in the original app and in this app I imported bootstrap core files and added them to the index file. So the css is working but for some reason I cant bind this to the div.

Please explain to me why this wont work without ng2 and how to fix it.

Comment: You said you used ng2-bootstrap in the original app. So you aren't in the new one? I never used ng2-bootsrap, but I'm willing to bet that `collapse` is a directive from that library. You would need to grab that from the library, or if you can't use the library, create your own collapse directive

Comment: You are very right. I just found an example online of someone making a collapse div and in the example he creates a directive. So your assumption must be correct. Learning experience. Do you think its better to write the directive or use the library? For the apps overall performance do you think it makes a difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error:

`Can't bind to 'collapse' since it isn't a known property of 'div'.`

means that Angular doesn't know how to bind to "collapse" because it's not a native HTML property, and there is nothing defined in your code that says how to process that. Like the comment above said, you need to either create a Angular 2 directive that understands how to deal with the collapse property or import the directive from another place.